# Video Container for 1080p video for SD DVD (using Apple suite)

Tags: video, dvd

This may be a bit of a stretch to post here (in terms of whether people will have an answer), since this is a fairly specific question about video work, although I am performing the entirety of this work within FCP 7, Compressor, and DVD Studio Pro.

I have 2 hours of footage edited from a HD Camcorder in FCP 7, and I need to get it onto a DVD. I want to use the highest quality container I can, and I want to be able to author and preferably burn the DVD within DVD Studio Pro. Unfortunately, DVDSP doesn't support MPEG-4, which is one of the nicest containers to put 1080p video into. It supports MPEG, which offers considerably less options for compression, and data rates.

Ultimately, my question is HOW can I export my video out of FCP (or Compressor) so that I'm sitting on a high quality file that will fit on one DVD and be compatible with DVD Studio Pro (4.7GB)? I just finished a 24 hour Compressor job with the default setting "HD DVD 60 minutes", but it gave me a 5.1GB file, which is of no use to me. The aspect ratio is also forced and it looks terrible.

HELP!

Comment: I was looking arround for answers and found your post in Creative Cow. hahaha Yeah, it seems to me you wont be able to do this keeping your video in 1080p. Sorry, and but good luck!
http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/155/881011

Comment: thanks for posting the CC link. I actually realized that CC would be a better community (nothing against StackExchange) because of their volume of professionals. I hope that I helped a few people with the post.

Answer (score 1):

*Just to get this 'answered' for anyone else who might come across this question.*

**There is no way to get 1080p or 1080i video onto a DVD.** DVD's only support SD images (this goes for the disks themselfs, and the players).

You can however use [BluRay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-ray_Disc) to burn HD video, though this would require a BluRay burner and a BluRay player.

Have a look here for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video

Answer (score 0):

SD dvd only works with mpeg-2, and doesn't support HD signal, export your video as SD 16:9 from compressor, if you want HD on a disk has to be blu-ray